# How can I click and drag to manually sort photos

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable Windows Vista / 7 Explorer’s “auto sort” after file copying?](https://superuser.com/questions/279200/how-can-i-disable-windows-vista-7-explorers-auto-sort-after-file-copying)

On my previous PC with Windows XP, I could click and drag my photos easily - comparing several of the same shot and deleting those that weren't as good - then number them in the order I want them and rename them so they stayed in that order with their captions.

Windows 7 won't let me click and drag photos - I have to look at the entire camera card worth of downloaded pics and then rename them with different numbers before the pictures change positions.  Since I don't always take the pictures in the order I want to save them in, this is really time consuming and difficult.

Anyone know of any free programs that will let me click and drag photos again?
Thanks much,
Mary

Answer (score 2):

In windows explorer, you can always click and drag files. If you are unable to click and drag, try to `Right Click > Copy` and then paste them the same way anywhere you'd like [Maybe on you desktop]. Now try dragging them. It should work.
And as for Photo managing applications that help you organize, try using Pisasa or use the inbuilt Windows live photo gallery.I think that if you dont want to download anything, Windows live photo gallery is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: "In windows explorer, you can always click and drag files" - But that doesn't change their order as the OP wants (due to Win7's annoying "auto sort"), and which was possible in earlier versions of Windows. You don't seriously think pasting tons of files to the desktop just to change their order is a viable solution, do you?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors. I have edited it now. As for the desktop thing, I just assumed that the user was inexperienced.

Comment: No, sadly, this is a bug in Windows, although MS prefers to call it a "feature".