# Is there a way for Windows 7 Windows explorer to act like XP Windows explorer when refreshing?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable Windows Vista / 7 Explorer’s “auto sort” after file copying?](https://superuser.com/questions/279200/how-can-i-disable-windows-vista-7-explorers-auto-sort-after-file-copying)

Example: You have a RAR file, which you unpack.

In Windows XP the unpacked files & folders would now be on the bottom of the list, until you pressed F5 (or Refresh) upon which they would take their place, depending on whether you had sorting by Name, by Type, by Date ...

In Windows 7, that refreshing is automatic, making it sometimes harder to see which files just got unpacked.

Is there a way in Windows 7 to revert to the old way of doing things?

Comment: Obviously you can achieve the same result –– seeing what files just got unpacked –– by sorting by Date modified (or Date created, if WinRAR sets the modification dates on the files).

Comment: @Scott - WinRAR doesn't modify the date.